# Copy text with colors to clipboard

Tags: java, windows, swing, clipboard

As the title says, how can I copy colored/styled text to the windows clipboard in Java?

The text is located in a `JEditorPane` like this:

```
JEditorPane je = new JEditorPane("text/html","a <font color=\"yellow\">banana</font>");
```

After selecting the text and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, I want to copy and paste the text in word with the style still active.

Comment: From where to where? How is it colored?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be copied as plain text. You need to use CF_HTML or Rich Text Format.